# what is wrong with "He related to the bears."?

Tags: verbs, tenses

what is wrong with "He related to the bears." ?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it. Well, except maybe psychologically.  Depends on what kind of relations he made.

Comment: Who told you there was anything wrong with it?  Can you elaborate on what you think it means, or what it's supposed to mean?

Comment: Now that's just *weird*!!

Comment: _He related to the bears rather than to any of the rodents_. Context is everything.

Comment: @Hot Licks - in the *platonic* sense. Sheesh!

Comment: "He relates to the bears" sounds more grammatically correct, but I'm not sure how it makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

If it was meant he was socially connected or biologically related to the bears, you must say:

> He **was** related to the bears.

If it was meant he empathized, or mentally related, to the bears, then this is correct:

> He related to the bears.